# Increasing the item limit for discussions web part on Community home page

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, community-site

How can you increase the number of discussions displayed on a Community Homepage in the Discussions List web part?

If I edit the page and select the web part, the List Tab is displayed in the ribbon, but the Modify View option is disabled.

There also does not appear any specific web part properties that relate to this.